# How to create sample pcap file in python with dummy data, without using tcpdump?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I do not have permission to perform `tcpdump` on my test server, without `sudo`.

As of now I just want to create a dummy pcap file like original ones with some sample data and use it for some testing.

To replicate original, cat should look like:

```
<<▒
```

Below command to read it in a human way should give o/p like below.

```
tcpdump -qns 0 -X -r test_abc.pcap
reading from file abc.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
22:06:04.309992 IP xxx.xxx.x.xx.xxxxx > xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx: tcp 0
        0x0000:  4500 0028 57ef 4000 7b06 0199 c0a8 015b  E..(W.@.{......[
        0x0010:  2b94 b8b0 ae38 0016 48d1 ea1b b5f0 3568  +....8..H.....5h
        0x0020:  5010 00fe 3bfa 0000 0000 0000 0000       P...;.........
```

If I try to write a `pcap` file with 0s and 1s or copy pasting above readable text, the file is not like real `pcap` file, because the data is readable with cat, which is not the case for real `pcap` files.

Comment: **Require administrator access to access hardware memory (for all inbound/outbound packets).**

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to generate a pcap from scratch, you should look at [Scapy](https://scapy.net/).  This will be especially good for you since you are thinking of using Python anyway.

Using Scapy, you can programmatically generate packets in memory and then write them save them easily as a valid pcap file using the `wrpcap()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hex editor (e.g. xxd which is built-in in most *nix systems).